# How we can access the properties of an installed printer as we get by going to

Tags: c#

How we can access the properties of an installed printer as we get by going to

Start-->Printer & Faxes-->Right click on the Printername-->Properties dialogue of that printer

using C# code to change the printer settings as we do using the above procedure. I want to open the property dialogue directly by giving the name of the printer

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocumentProperties Win API function.

Answer (score 0):

Try [How to show a popup window for printer properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14379/How-to-show-a-popup-window-for-printer-properties) tutorial from CodeProject.

If it's ok to let the user see a list of all the printers, you can use [`System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx).

Comment: i need to set print properties in run time

Answer (score 0):

To open the properties dialog directly, you can [use printui.dll](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/37367-how-to-access-to-printer-properties-dialog-box-directly/):

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /p /n "printer name"
```

From c#, that would be:

```
Process.Start("rundll32", "printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /p /n \"printer name\"");
```